Edge Crease for fine detail not working
I'm still a beginner and not sure if the edge crease is the best way to go about what I'm trying to accomplish, but basically, I'm trying to make a thin, 90 deg. cut into the outsole of this shoe.  I started by using the knife tool to make the shape I wanted, beveled the shape to the appropriate thickness, and then extruded downwards into the outsole.  I tried adding edge creases on both the top and bottom edges of the shape, and proceeding to mess with the bevel weight to no avail.
What the edge crease is producing:

What it looks like inside:

Is the edge crease the right tool to use here?  I tried mark sharp and just beveling those blue edges, but I don't really know what I'm doing.

Should I have applied the solidifier modifier before making this cut?

Edge Crease is probably what you want, it prevents the Subdivision Surface to happen on these edges if you are using this modifier, but it may not work fine, maybe share this part of your object?
